# AddEventListener is not working for one element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

AddEventListener is working fine for the first function but not triggering the second one, not even showing in the `console.log`. Please see where I'm going wrong?

```
    <ul id="nv">
      <li class="nvItem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nvItem"><a href="#the-story">Story</a></li>
      <li class="nvItem"><a href="#comic-book">Comic</a></li>
      <li class="nvItem"><a href="#creatures">Creatures</a></li>
      <li class="nvItem"><a href="#the-path">Path</a></li>
      <li class="nvItem"><a href="#artists">Nikal</a></li>                      
    </ul>
```

Please ignore the id `mn`

```
const navigation = document.getElementById("nv");
const menu = document.getElementById("mn");
const navItems = document.getElementsByClassName("nvItem")

menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navigation.style.setProperty("--childenNumber", navigation.children.length);

  navigation.classList.toggle("active");
  menu.classList.toggle("active");
  console.log("---Active---");
});

navItems.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navigation.classList.toggle("nonActive");
    menu.classList.toggle("nonActive");
    console.log("---Deactive---");
  });
```

Comment: Since navItems is not a single element, you cannot add an event listener to it directly. You need to loop over navItems and add the event listener in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take some time and read this about event listeners:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

They can not be attached to NodeLists
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

We can get around this by looping through the Nodes and applying an EventListener to each node.

Because you have  tags you may have some side effects. I would recommend pointer-events: none or some other kind of prevention on the  to stop default behavior.

```js
const navigation = document.getElementById("nv");
const menu = document.getElementById("mn");
const navItems = document.getElementsByClassName("nvItem")

menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navigation.style.setProperty("--childenNumber", navigation.children.length);

  navigation.classList.toggle("active");
  menu.classList.toggle("active");
  console.log("---Active---");
});

Array.from(navItems).forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", e => {
    navigation.classList.toggle("nonActive");
    menu.classList.toggle("nonActive");
    console.log("---Deactive---");
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="mn">
  menu
</div>
<ul id="nv">
  <li class="nvItem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nvItem"><a href="#the-story">Story</a></li>
  <li class="nvItem"><a href="#comic-book">Comic</a></li>
  <li class="nvItem"><a href="#creatures">Creatures</a></li>
  <li class="nvItem"><a href="#the-path">Path</a></li>
  <li class="nvItem"><a href="#artists">Jozef</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Dan, Thank you for the relevant articles and the solution